# twilio video code leaving video tag behind when I detach track

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, twilio, twilio-video

So Im a bit confused.

The way this works, is each person in my video call already has space in the ui when they join. When they turn on their video the code attaches their track to their respective div space on the ui.

Just for clarity here is the start video code. It is unrelated to this question, but good for context.

```
startvideo(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then((stream)=>{
      createLocalVideoTrack({
        deviceId: stream.id
      }).then(localVideoTrack =>{
        return this.videoclient.localParticipant.publishTrack((localVideoTrack)).then(publication =>{
          this.localvideotrack = localVideoTrack;
          let div = document.getElementById( this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid + 'vid');
          div.appendChild(localVideoTrack.attach());
          this.removenovideohtml(this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid);
          this.mms.getDevicesOnComputer();
          this.devicessubscription = this.mms.receiveDevices()
            .subscribe(
              (req: any)=>{
                this.devicesoptions = req;
              }
            );
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

and here is the end video code, this is in context:

```
endvideo(){
    if(this.localvideotrack != null){
      let div = document.getElementById( this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid + 'vid');
      this.localvideotrack.detach(div);
      this.localvideotrack.stop();
      this.videoclient.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(this.localvideotrack);
      this.addremovevideohtml(this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid);
    }
  }
```

now look what happens when I start and stop the video three times

[image: 2 blank chat boxes when there should only be the video]

and the html of the picture above

[image: the html]

I have tried to add code to then manually remove the video elements after detaching the `track` but I have had no success. Wondering if you guys can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`detach` method](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.15.1/docs/VideoTrack.html#detach__anchor) actually returns the media element that the track was previously attached to, which allows you to then remove the media element from the page if you no longer need it.

You don't need to pass `div` to `detach` either, the video track is aware of the element it is attached to. This means you don't need to do the `getElementById` lookup either.

I'd recommend you update the `endvideo` function to the following:

```js
endvideo(){
    if(this.localvideotrack != null){
      const mediaElements = this.localvideotrack.detach();
      mediaElements.forEach(mediaElement => mediaElement.remove());
      this.localvideotrack.stop();
      this.videoclient.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(this.localvideotrack);
      this.addremovevideohtml(this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its amazing and yet really painful how easy it was to fix this.

Here is the endvideo() code unchaged:

```
endvideo(){
    if(this.localvideotrack != null){
      let div = document.getElementById( this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid + 'vid');
      this.localvideotrack.detach(div);
      this.localvideotrack.stop();
      
      this.videoclient.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(this.localvideotrack);
      this.addremovevideohtml(this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid);
    }
```

now here is the new endvideo() code:

```
endvideo(){
    if(this.localvideotrack != null){
      let div = document.getElementById( this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid + 'vid');
      this.localvideotrack.detach(div);
      this.localvideotrack.stop();
      div.innerHTML = '';
      this.videoclient.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(this.localvideotrack);
      this.addremovevideohtml(this.videoclient.localParticipant.sid);
    }
  }
```

this is the difference:

```
div.innerHTML = '';
```